# With JS fetch , Post data to MVC Action Method

Tags: javascript

I have seen similar questions but no matter what I did, this code doesn't work. I did exactly what other answers suggested. I can't debug the issue. Please help if you can...

Basically I am trying to post data from .js file to the JsonResult method in MVC controller. 
my DealVm class is like that.

```
public class DealVM
{
    public DealVM()
    {
        DealID = 0;
        DealName = "";
    }
    public int DealID { get; set; }
    public string DealName { get; set; }
}
```

**My Home controller method is**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostPurchaseOrder(DealVM  dealVM)
    {
        var d = dealVM;
        return Json("");
    }
```

**And js file is**

```
function postData2(vue, url, showmessage, onSuccess) { 

var TestData = { dealVM: { DealID: 77, DealName: "SeventySeven" } };

fetch('https://localhost:123456/Home/PostPurchaseOrder/', {  
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(TestData.dealVM)
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(function (data) {
        // rest of the Code
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error);
        vue.$data.serverRequest = false;
    })
```

}

I tried many things but still post can't pass the data to the postData2 method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Asp.NetCore, you have to add [[FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) attribute beside your param name in your controller action for complex JSON data types:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostPurchaseOrder([FromBody]DealVM  dealVM)
    {
        var d = dealVM;
        return Json("");
    }
```